# PHP HTML and array - show result from array in specific way

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I have a litle problem for showing result from array.

I want to show the information from array at html table but in cpecific way. I made a picture which shows how I want the result to look like
I have this array:

```
$array[] = array('date' => $datesMonth, 'buro' => $buro_name, 'pechalba' => $pechalba, 'ime' => $ime);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($array,1).'</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-01
            [buro] => Kate
            [pechalba] => 48.66
            [ime] => silvi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-02
            [buro] => Kate
            [pechalba] => 135.09
            [ime] => silvi
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-03
            [buro] => Kate
            [pechalba] => 288.03
            [ime] => cveti
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-04
            [buro] => Kate
            [pechalba] => 95.36
            [ime] => silvi
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-05
            [buro] => Kate
            [pechalba] => 74.62
            [ime] => maya
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-01
            [buro] => Sisi
            [pechalba] => 54.3
            [ime] => ivo
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-02
            [buro] => Sisi
            [pechalba] => 169.01
            [ime] => ivo
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-03
            [buro] => Sisi
            [pechalba] => 216.31
            [ime] => ivo
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-04
            [buro] => Sisi
            [pechalba] => 285.6
            [ime] => ivo
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-05
            [buro] => Sisi
            [pechalba] => 11.7
            [ime] => ivo
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-01
            [buro] => Gala
            [pechalba] => 20.44
            [ime] => maya
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-02
            [buro] => Gala
            [pechalba] => 55.49
            [ime] => maya
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-03
            [buro] => Gala
            [pechalba] => 161.23
            [ime] => maya
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-04
            [buro] => Gala
            [pechalba] => 69.29
            [ime] => cveti
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-05
            [buro] => Gala
            [pechalba] => 36.13
            [ime] => silvi
        )

)
```

I want to show the information from the array in html table at that way:

[image]

Is it possible to do that with php and if yes how can i do that?

Comment: group them by name first so that you can assign each name into their respective tables, after creating the tables, the rest is just touches of css

Comment: Is my answer what you were looking for? Give me a feedback if it helped or if you have any questions

Comment: @NoOorZ24  Here is the result from your  answer [link](http://encyclopedia.lubopitko-bg.com/images/Untitled3.jpg)

Comment: Check my updated answer, it should work now

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Nice! You are ninja! Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

This generates table from array, styling table is up to you.

```
$groups = [];
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if (!in_array($data['buro'], $groups)) {
        $groups[$data['buro']][] = $data;
    }
}
// create header
echo "<tr>";
foreach($groups as $key => $group) {
    echo "<th colspan='3'>" . $key . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

// create body
$stack = count(array_values($groups)[0]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $stack; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        echo "<td>" . $group[$i]['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $group[$i]['pechalba'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $group[$i]['ime'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Update:** I run it locally and fixed my errors, now it seems to work as intended

Comment: It is not working! [link](http://encyclopedia.lubopitko-bg.com/images/Untitled3.jpg) Here is the result from your code!

Comment: @BorislavRazvanski could you add output of print_r($groups) and image of how code is implemented?

Comment: @BorislavRazvanski does this line really look like $groups[] = [$data['buro'] => $data]; and not $groups[] = [$data]; ? Have you really not put $array instead of $groups in foreach loops?

Comment: Here is my code: [link](http://encyclopedia.lubopitko-bg.com/images/text.txt) And the result here: [link](http://encyclopedia.lubopitko-bg.com/images/Untitled3.jpg)

Comment: Ooo nice! You are ninja! Thank you!